# How to access textfield input from javascript variable in yii

Tags: javascript, php, yii

I am using java script function in yii _form view in this function i store value in variable and these variable i want to access in yii textfield

so please tell me how access textfield input from javascript variable in yii
Here is my javascript function i try this but its showing me blank result

```
<script language="javascript">
function get_data(element)
    {
       var te_id = $(element).val();
           document.getElementById('data').value=te_id;
    }
</script>
<?php echo $form->TextField($model,'data',array('value'=>'')); ?>
```

Comment: how are you calling this `get_data` method?

Answer (score 2):

Your code shows that you want to access the values, after initializing it, so you should add html options :

```
<?php echo $form->TextField($model,'data',array('onclick'=>'get_data(this)')); ?>
```

an use your get_data function .

or assign an ID to it

```
<?php echo $form->TextField($model,'data',array('id'=>'myInput')); ?>
```

and use a button to do the change:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#someButton').click(function(){ // change the value on some button click
        var inputValue = $('#myInput').val();
        //now assign it to ther place
        $('#otherInput').val(inputValue);
     });
});
```